# How to use Spring Security OAuth2 with Apache Wicket?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, wicket

I would like to use an OAuth2 authentication with my Apache Wicket website.

My website is using Spring Boot and Spring Security for the authentication part, but I would like to use the @AuthorizeInstantiation Wicket annotation to protect the pages.

Can I use these frameworks together and how ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can combine them!

See wicket-auth-roles module for inspiration how to implement authentication in Wicket. The difference with Spring Security is that you need to use `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` to get the currently logged in user/principal.

If you decide to extend from `AbstractAuthenticatedWebSession` then its `public abstract boolean isSignedIn();` should use Spring Security APIs to get the Principal.